# Kafka 0.8 producer throughput test

Tags: testing, producer-consumer, throughput, apache-kafka

According to Kafka official document, the producer throughput is about 50MB/S. But I do some test, the producer throughout is only about 2MB/S. The test environment is the same with document says. One producer, One broker, One Zookeeper are in an independent machine. Message size is 100 bytes, batch size is 200, the flush interval is 600 messages. The test environment is the same, the configuration is the same. Then why is there such a big gap in my test result and what the document says?

Comment: Is the hardware and OS environment the same as well?